# What controller is called when category is clicked from top menu in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, category, controllers

I want to know which **controller** is called when I click on **category** from the top menu bar.
For eg : When I click on **Men** it opens page with url **http://127.0.0.1/Magento21/men.html**. But I don't see any controller name in the **url**.
What controller is called in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some tricly,you can find a  url's route name, controller name,Action name from Html content body.

In magento, whenever ***page is render html content***  and have html body`<body>` tag then this html's have  some few classes.

Those classes must indicate current page  `url's route name, controller name,Action name`

like ***`frontendofModule-ControllerName-ActionName`***

For **http://127.0.0.1/Magento21/men.html** body may look that

> class="page-products categorypath-men category-men
>   catalog-category-view page-layout-2columns-left"

Here catalog-category-view this indicate that url

- frontend Route name **catalog**
- Controller is  **Category**
- Action name is **View**

That means your  current page action file is

```
Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on any category, following controller is called.

**Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View**